# resque scheduler unrecognized signal SIGUSR1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

I have absolutely no idea how to run my resque scheduler. When i enqueue a single task and run it manually it works fine but when i try to implement resque scheduler using the command rake resque:scheduler --trace, i get ArgumentError: unsupported signal SIGUSR1. Below are the files needed for resque scheduler:

## config/initializers/resque.rb

```
require 'resque/failure/multiple'
require 'resque/failure/redis'
Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes = [Resque::Failure::Redis]
Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::Multiple
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'jobs', '*.rb')].each { |file| require file }
config = YAML.load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/resque.yml"))[Rails.env]
Resque.redis = Redis.new(host: config['host'], port: config['port'], db: config['db'])
```

## config/resque.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  db: 6
development:
  <<: *defaults
test:
  <<: *defaults
staging:
  <<: *defaults
production:
  <<: *defaults
```

## lib/tasks/resque.rake

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'
require 'yaml'

task 'resque:setup' => :environment

namespace :resque do
  task :setup_schedule => :setup do
    require 'resque-scheduler'

    # If you want to be able to dynamically change the schedule,
    # uncomment this line.  A dynamic schedule can be updated via the
    # Resque::Scheduler.set_schedule (and remove_schedule) methods.
    # When dynamic is set to true, the scheduler process looks for
    # schedule changes and applies them on the fly.
    # Note: This feature is only available in >=2.0.0.
    # Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true

    # The schedule doesn't need to be stored in a YAML, it just needs to
    # be a hash.  YAML is usually the easiest.
    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml"))
  end

  task :scheduler => :setup_schedule
end
```

## config/resque_schedule.yml

```
run_my_job:
  cron: '30 6 * * 1'
  class: 'MyJob'
  queue: myjob
  args:
  description: "Runs MyJob"
```

Here's the error message for the rake resque:scheduler command:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jUrH.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just found out that Windows doesn't support the SIGUSR1 signal. Here's a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx) of supported signals in Windows. The solution will be to use another OS such as Ubuntu to run the operation and it runs with no problems.